# Entity Framework - Invalid Column Error on non-existent column

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have 2 tables in a plain old 1-n relationship: `Invoice` and `WorkOrder`. An `Invoice` can have many `WorkOrders` and a `WorkOrder` can have a single `Invoice`. Earth-shaking, I know.

Here's my `Invoice`:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    // some fields....

    public virtual IList<WorkOrder> WorkOrders { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my `WorkOrder`:

```
public class WorkOrder
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid InvoiceId { get; set; }

    public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
}
```

When I go to query for Invoices, I get this error:

> Invalid column name 'Invoice_Id2'.

When I look at the `WorkOrder` table in SSMS I find not one, but 3 columns referencing `Invoice`: `InvoiceId`, `Invoice_Id`, and `Invoice_Id1`.

Obviously something has gone very wrong in EF figuring out what I want it to do.

I did manage to find an FK for `Invoice_Id2`, which I deleted, but I'm still having the problem.

Comment: Have you taken a look at your model (the designer surface)? There may be some auto-added column to some entity type while importing in a certain scenario.

Comment: What approach you are using?

Comment: I'm using Code First Migrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that I had made some mistakes not elaborated above (bc I didn't think they were relevant, natch). Namely I had a bunch of getter methods in my `Invoice` entity that returned `IList<WorkOrder>` and EF was mistakenly picking up on those as navigation properties.

As far as I can tell, once you've created a table that's been jacked up that way, you're better off dropping the offending tables, adding `[NotMapped]` attributes to the troublesome properties, and recreating the table. Hopefully you don't have important production data in those tables already. I lucked out there.

I was really surprised those getters would be picked up by the ORM as Navigation properties, so beware that in the future. Perhaps being less clever and doing straight methods in the future would be smarter.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this type of error happens when EF is trying to match a relationship based on faulty navigational properties. For instance if you had:

```
public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
public virtual Invoice Invice { get; set; }
```

Notice the misspelling above. EF will expect there to be a column in the database called `Invice_Id`. I'd check your related entities for misnamed navigational properties.